# What should be the return of lambda within another lambda

Tags: java, lambda

So, I have a code excerpt which goes like this (takes a string and divides it into key and value parameter)

```
Files.lines(Paths.get("src/main/files/end.log")).forEach( (p) ->
            chart.computeIfPresent(p.substring(0,2), (k, v) -> {
                try {
                    v.setEndTime(p.substring(3));
                } catch (ParseException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }));
```

But I don't really know what should I return in second lambda because neither variant works. Or is it supposed to work at all?

Comment: You're supposed to return the new value for the map. Since you are just mutating the object, you can do `return v;`

Comment: with `return v;` it compiles but doesn't seem to work properly, maybe the issue is in with the rest of the code

Comment: The question is not really clear with what is the type of `chart`, what are you intending to do within the remapping function?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming `chart` is a `Map` and [computeIfPresent](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Map.html#computeIfPresent-K-java.util.function.BiFunction-) is a method which takes `key` and `BiFunction` as argument

```
default V computeIfPresent(K key,
                       BiFunction<? super K,? super V,? extends V> remappingFunction)
```

> If the value for the specified key is present and non-null, attempts to compute a new mapping given the key and its current mapped value.

So this method is used to compute a new value for an existed key in map, so `BuFunction` takes the `key,oldvalue` as arguments and returned value will be the new computed value for that key

**Example :**

```
Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();

map.put("10", "Deadpool");

System.out.println(map);  //{10=Deadpool}
```

Now computing new value to key `10` using `computeIfPresent`

```
  map.computeIfPresent("10", (key,oldVal)->"Iron Man");
System.out.println(map);   // {10=Iron Man}
```

So in your code you have to return the new value that need to be associate with key

```
Files.lines(Paths.get("src/main/files/end.log")).forEach( (p) ->
        chart.computeIfPresent(p.substring(0,2), (k, v) -> {
            try {
                v.setEndTime(p.substring(3));
            } catch (ParseException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        //return value for key p.substring(0,2)
        }));
```

Comment: Does this compile? How did you infer the type of the `Map`(asking for `v.setEndTime` doesn't really make sense)?

Comment: I just told OP what does computeifpresent does and how to use it with an example@Naman

Comment: Which is not the question anyway.